# Как исправить подсвечивание легенды серии при наведении на саму серию в TeeChart

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin, teechart

Есть чарт с несколькими сериями. Есть кнопка, что делает часть их видимыми\невидимыми (`Visible := False`).

В чарте, как я понимаю, "из коробки" встроена такая фича: при наведении мыши на серию, её легенда выделяется красным. Но, когда часть серий скрыта, эта фича неправильно работает, похоже учитывая и невидимые.

Например, три серии, вторая невидимая. Наводишь на первую - подсвечивает первую легенду, наводишь на третью - подсвечивает вторую легенду, а т.к. она невидима, результат немного предсказуем.

Как это можно поправить? Есть ли свойство, что этим управляет в чарте?

Edit: Понял, что можно в `MouseMove`  проверять `Series.Clicked` у каждой серии, и вручную менять цвет соотвеnствующей легенды, но как это скажется на производительности, если серий может быть десятки\сотни, в каждой сотни\тысячи точек. Ну и как вырубить стандартное подсвечивание пока неясно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Chart1.Legend.Selected.Hover.Visible := False`

Comment: А можете подсказать насчёт оптимальности  проверки всех Series.Clicked  постоянно? С одной вроде выглядит затратно, но с другой, в стандартной реализации примерно так же сделано наверное

Comment: Для длинных серий затратно, конечно, однако они в любом случае тормозят (когда я последний раз (давно) исходники видел, там на каждый чих пересчитывалось всё, что можно простым перебором) . Как внутри сделано с clicked - не знаю.